# Encrypted disk passphrase prompt

Tags: boot, encryption, ecryptfs

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 with an encrypted drive, I expected to see a passphrase prompt before the normal prompt for login. Instead, I only see the usual bootup process until it stops on a blank screen. The first time, I waited a while but eventually decided it was waiting for the passphrase. Once I typed the passphrase (there was still nothing on the screen, no prompt, no indication that I was typing anything), the system displayed my login prompt after a few more seconds. Anyone know why I'm not seeing the passphrase prompt?

Comment: i have seen this happen in a virtual machine with 18.04. I don't know why. As I could use the system I did not look for a solution. It may have to do something with the display driver at this pre-boot stage, but that is just my guess. The version 20.04 did not have this problem.

Comment: "*After entering it, the system displayed my login prompt.*" - Please edit your question and describe the problem in more detail. This is what is supposed to happen...

Comment: @Nmath I've edited the post but, according to the installation instructions I read in various places, what is "supposed to happen" is that I should see a prompt like, "Please unlock disk sda5_crypt". I don't see that. Just a blank screen. I'm wondering if there's a settings buried somewhere to control that.

Comment: Do you have more than one display connected?

Comment: Yes, I have two.